# Django forms: set initial value

Tags: python, django

I have a form that tries to register a 'currently working on' project to a department.

models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Project(models.Model):
    projectname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

forms.py

```
class ProjectChoiceField(ModelChoiceField): # return a list of projects for the department form.
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s" % obj.projectname

class SetDepartmentProjectForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SetDepartmentProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.fields['projectstring']: # no default set
            self.fields['projectstring'] = ProjectChoiceField(Project.objects.filter(department=self.instance), required=False)
        else:
            project = Project.objects.get(projectname=self.fields['projectstring'])
            self.fields['projectstring'] = ProjectChoiceField(Project.objects.filter(department=self.instance), required=False, initial=project.pk)

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['dept_name', 'address', 'projectstring']
```

This works ok for creating a dropdown set of projects if there is no value set, but when it is set to some projectname value - the initial arg (Project.pk) does not select the correct project as the intial value in the form.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by setting `initial=self.instance.related_fieldname.pk`.

Comment: initial=self.instance.related_fieldname is a string - it has no pk. Do you mean to lookup the pk of the related OtherModel? ie. is this what the widget uses as the value for the ChoiceField.

Comment: It should be an instance of `OtherModel`, yes?

Comment: OtherModel choices are indeed the pk of the other model - but even if I select the correct pk and choose intial=other_model.pk - it still defaults to nothing selected ---------, see my edit.

Comment: So your answer is not correct in this case, and something else is the problem.